# The name 'AppDate' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am getting the an error in the following code. Cant seem to find a solution

```
 using (var context = new CatLiveDataContext()) 
            {
                DateTime AppDate;
                var fieldsaleId = context.FieldSales.Where(fs => fs.CompanyId == companyId && fs.IsClosed).Select(fs =>(int?) fs.Id).SingleOrDefault();
                if (fieldsaleId != null)
                {
                var fieldsale = context.FieldSales.Where(fs => fs.Id == fieldsaleId).SingleOrDefault();
                var calenderitem = fieldsale.CalendarItem;

                    if (calenderitem != null)
                    {
                        AppDate = calenderitem.StartTime;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AppDate = DateTime.Today;
                    }
                }
            }

            using (var repository = new TaskRepository())
            {
                repository.CreateDesiredDirectoryTask(companyId, directoryName, directoryEdition, directoryHeading, userStaffId, AppDate);
                repository.SubmitChanges();
            }
```

Error:The name 'AppDate' does not exist in the current context

I am getting the error when I pass the appdate to the method which I from the linq query.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared `AppDate` within the first `using` statement, so it's not in scope outside that first statement. Just move the declaration to before that statement... or put the whole of the first `using` statement into a separate method for clarity:

```
// Rename according to real meaning
DateTime appDate = FetchAppDate(companyId, fieldsaleId);
using (var repository = new TaskRepository())
{
    repository.CreateDesiredDirectoryTask(companyId, directoryName,
        directoryEdition, directoryHeading, userStaffId, AppDate);
    repository.SubmitChanges();
}
```